# How to clear QTableView

Tags: pyqt4, qtableview

i have a QTableView. I am Querying data from database using `QtSql.QSqlQuery`.

```
SQL = 'SELECT * FROM table1'
Query = QtSql.QSqlQuery(database)
Query.prepare(SQL)
Query.exec_()

model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
model.setTable('Table')
model.setQuery(Query)

proxy = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel()
proxy.setSourceModel(model)

QTableView.setModel(proxy)
```

Everything is working file the Query result is show in the `QTableView`.
My Issues is when i change the `SQL`  statement which results `Query` to return 0 records, I need to clear the data and the cells in the `QTableView`

I tried using `QTableView.clear()` its clearing the data in the cells leaving behind empty rows and columns. How can i clear `QTAbleView` completly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My research on clearing data worked.

I Used `proxy.deleteLater()`

Hope someone could get benefited who comes across the same situation

Comment: This removes the widget and would not be the best method for clearing the data from a QTableView

Answer (score 3):

In c++ there is a reset function for QAbstractItemView.
you could say

`yourTableView.reset();`

Comment: This doesn't clear the data.

Answer (score 1):

What I prefer using in this situation is a bit of a workaround, due to the limitations of QTableView

In my own personal program, I decided instead to hide the rows and columns of the QTableView, making it to appear as though it is set to default and blank. The reason for this is, if you delete the widget, you need to replace it and this also resets all of the object's properties. This could theoretically force you to re-assign all the properties of your QTableView every time you need it to just display as blank or cleared. Instead of deleting the widget, this proposed option can be done with just two simple loops and when you refresh your table and want to display the values again, just two simple loops again, gets the job done.

There are multiple ways to populate a QTableView, but whichever you use, you just need to iterate through the rows and columns of your table. Below is the method I use, based on a class that inherits from QtCore.QAbstractTableModel so that when I call `dataFrame` it returns a pandas dataframe of the QTableView data.

If you need to hide the table:

```
for _row in range(len(yourQTableView.model().dataFrame.index)):
    yourQTableView.hideRow(_row)

for _col, col_name in enumerate(yourQTableView.model().dataFrame.columns):
    yourQTableView.hideColumn(_col)
```

If you need to show the table:

```
for _row in range(len(yourQTableView.model().dataFrame.index)):
    yourQTableView.showRow(_row)

for _col, col_name in enumerate(yourQTableView.model().dataFrame.columns):
    yourQTableView.showColumn(_col)
```

To me, this is the easiest method and gets me the result I want. I can't think of a reason why this method wouldn't be preferred over deleting the widget altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.table_view.model().setRowCount(0)
```